# Piping output into multiple files iteratively on Unix

Tags: bash, unix, file-io, pipe

I've got a large amount of `.mid` files in directory `foo`, and when I apply the command `midicsv bar.mid > bar.csv` , a `.mid` file is converted into a newly created `.csv` file of the same name.

How can I do this iteratively for hundreds of `.mid` files, outputting the result into files of their respective names in `.csv` format?

Sorry if I am being unclear at any moment, Bash scripting isn't my peak skill.

Comment: I'm reopening this question, would it be possible to this exact thing recursively through all subdirectories of the home directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop and parameter expansion.

```
for f in foo/*.mid; do
    midicsv "$f" > "${f%.mid}.csv"
done
```

Comment: I don't really know bash scripting and its syntax, but this makes perfect sense when I read it. It works perfectly. You the real MVP, chepner.